# Using VLOOKUP or MATCH for cells that contain comma separated values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am trying to use either `VLOOKUP` or a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` for a small project I am working on in Google Sheets, but I am running into trouble when a cell contains comma-separated values.  I have provided an example below:

[image: Example]

**Column A** and **Column B** make up the search range, and **Column C** contains the search keys.  **Column D** uses the `VLOOKUP` method, and **Column E** uses the `INDEX` and `MATCH` method.  The formulas for the cells in the first row are as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&$C1&"*", A$1:B$4, 2, FALSE)
```

---

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4, MATCH("*"&$C1&"*", $A$1:$A$4, 0))
```

**Columns D** and **E** should spell out "SUCCESS" vertically if everything works correctly, but obviously, there are some issues.  When I originally started looking for help, I found the method of appending a wildcard character (*) to the beginning and end of the search key in order to disregard text before or after the value I am searching for.  This works except when the criteria for one search key can match a different search key, for example, when I am searching in **Row 1** for "Pg 3" but "Pg 32" and "Pg 33" also exist.  The problem only seems to occur when the value I am searching for is not in a cell by itself AND when it is preceded by a "matching" value in an earlier row (e.g. "Pg 33" matching the "Pg 3" key in **Row 1** and "Pg 64" matching the "Pg 6" key in **Row 7**).

Unfortunately, in the project I am working on, I will not be able to sort the range into alphanumeric order, so any help towards a workaround is appreciated, preferably just using formulas and not delving into Google Apps Script.  Hopefully, my explanation is clear enough, and I have no preference whether I use `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1:C, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(A1:A, ",")&"♠"&B1:B, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠")), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I am going through your formula, and I am having trouble understanding some of it, especially what the purpose of the diamond and spade symbols is.  Would you mind explaining your process?  Also, the example I provided was solely used to explain my issue, but when I implement this method in the actual project I am working on, is there a way to do this without creating an array since I do not want to return as many values as there are in the range I am searching through? I can provide a mock up of what that project will look like if you would like.

Comment: sure, it means nothing. ♦♠ are just a unique symbols for SPLIT formula. it can be any symbol ♥☺♫♀♂↨♣... basically what this formula do is split comma separated values from A column and assigning to each the value from B column. then it just performs simple vlookup in array

Comment: Ah, okay that makes a lot more sense.  I'm trying to go about this on my own, but if I end up having too much difficulty, do you know how I would go about implementing this in a single cell and not in an array?

Comment: for a single cell: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(A1:A, ",")&"♠"&B1:B, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠")), 2, 0)))`